# Facebook rocket for Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am a new Android developer. I want to connect my app with Facebook. I tried the Fb rocket code in following link:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-facebook-api-example-using-fbrocket/#idc-cover

When I am using the API key in the coding with my APP name, the status gets posted successfully, but when I use my own API key and my APP name, it goes till the login page and shows `Sorry, something went wrong`. Please help me solve my issue. I am very new to Android.

Comment: The standard api (its 14-07-2011) crashes on their official code samples (try changing screen orientation while there is a ProgressDialog "Now loading"). Also, I find official api very poorly written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you better use the github source for facebook,because it's standard api developed by facebook itself... from the link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk