# How can I login to facebook with my application?

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to do a news application that operates on Android, and I want to create my own login page that connects to Facebook and then can post something about news to facebook wall.

Questions:

1. Can I create my own login page and send my username, password, app_key to Facebook?
2. Is there an API reference you can recommend?

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942109/facebook-rocket-for-android/4943161#4943161

Comment: Hi this link may be useful to u
[facebook sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good place to start:

**Facebook Developers Site - Mobile Apps** 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

It describes how to do Single-Signon with Facebook on an Android device.